# Fastest and most efficient way to find the intersection of 2 stacks

Tags: python, algorithm, stack, intersection

Interview question: find the intersection of 2 stacks.
In python stacks are essentially just lists with pop and push function.
An intersection is the first item that is the same item within both stacks (and after all the following values are the same as well)

Right now I was thinking that I would first determine if their lengths are the same, if not, chop off the first few elements of the longer stack.

```
def intersect(s1, s2):
        diff = abs(len(s1) - len(s2))
        if diff > 0:
            for i in range diff:
                s1.pop()
        else:  
            while s1[0] != s2[0]:
                first = s1.pop()
                second = s2.pop()
                if compare(first, second) == True #use a comparator func to see if they're equal
                   return first
```

Otherwise I can't think of a better way than just popping the items in a linear order for both stacks at the same time and comparing the items.

I'm looking for a coded solution with an explanation! Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: If a stack only offers push and pop operations, I don't understand what you mean by "conduct a binary search".  How are you getting the items without popping?

Comment: It's great that you've explained your thoughts for a possible solution. It would be even better if you added a small code attempt of that solution. Your question is probably attracting downvotes due to the lack of code & because you ask for a coded solution.

Comment: I assume that you're allowed to destroy both stacks, but that you are only allowed to push, pop, or peek at the top item. You need to make that clear in your question.

Comment: How exactly do you define the intersection of two stacks? If the intersection is "the values that exist in both stacks", then you'll probably want to pop all the items from one of the stacks and place them in a dictionary. Then, for each item you pop off the other stack, if it exists in the dictionary, then it's an intersecting item.

Comment: Also, the interview question itself is a little vague. Do you just need to identify the items that are present in both stacks, or do you also need to consider the order of the items?

Comment: @JimMischel I'd use a set for that. But a dict would let you track the item positions as well, if that's required.

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes, a set would work, too, and would likely be more efficient. I don't see that there's a particular benefit to storing the position, unless "intersect" involves position. But then it would be more of a common subarray problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I don't quite understand how you could use binary search.

One possible way is to split list A and list B into two halves, so that you have 4 lists instead. Since there are no race conditions, you could just use multithreading to run the linear comparisons faster.

Here's a tutorial on  [how to use multithreading:](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multithreading-python-set-1/)

Comment: "Use multiple threads" isn't particularly useful advice without a description of what you'd use them for. Please explain your basic algorithm approach, and show how multiple threads would help improve the speed.

Answer (score 0):

Sets are pretty fast, you could just use a set

Consider this

```
In [51]: class Stack(list):
    ...:     def push(self, x):
    ...:         self.insert(0,x)
    ...:     def pop(self):      
    ...:         return list.pop(self, 0)
    ...:
    ...:

In [52]: a = Stack()

In [53]: a.push(5)

In [54]: a
Out[54]: [5]

In [55]: a.pop()
Out[55]: 5

In [56]: a
Out[56]: []

In [57]: b = Stack()

In [58]: a.push(1)

In [59]: a.push(2)

In [60]: a.push(3)

In [61]: a.push(4)

In [62]: b.push(2)

In [63]: b.push(3)

In [64]: b.push(4)

In [65]: b.push(5)

In [66]: a_s = set()

In [67]: b_s =set()

In [68]: while a != []:
    ...:     a_s.add(a.pop())
    ...:

In [69]: while b != []:
    ...:     b_s.add(b.pop())
    ...:

In [70]: answer = set.intersection(a_s, b_s)

In [71]: answer
Out[71]: {2, 3, 4}
```

Time Complexity

1. Iterate over stack 1 and add to set: `O(n)`
2. Iterate over stack 2 and add to set: `O(n)`. **OR just compute intersection here on the fly by querying the set you made above and adding to the answer set, will save you some time**
3. For each item in set1 perform a constant time lookup in set 2. : `O(n)`
4. Potentially print answer: `O(n)`
5. Overall: `O(n) * 3(or 4) ~= O(n)`

My reasoning for why you can't go faster without multi threading. 
Sorting is something you can do not have to look at element, but unless you can sort in true linear time it will take more time than `O(n)`. You have no way of computing an intersection without analysis each element of one stack in the context of the other stack. You can only optimize this contextual analysis from being an `O(n)` operation to being an `O(constant)` operation.

Also since you said you were using stacks that are specialized lists I don't thinking peeking at elements you haven't popped is allowed

Comment: If you do it this way why do you need two sets? Why not put stack1 in a set and instead of adding stack2 to a new set just the lookup in step two and skip step 3?

Comment: you are absolutely right,  as I was writing the answer I thought of that too, but since it wouldn't affect the complexity I let it be, I will edit it in as an optiization